# find primary object for cases and incidents in servicenow CRM

Tags: servicenow

We need to know is there any primary object available for cases and incidents in servicenow.

We have navigate to cases and incidents. In cases, we can see contact,account contracts etc. But there is no object is set as required.
In incidents, we couldn't see any objects.

So now our question is, is there any primary object available for cases and incidents.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Task is the common parent table for Incident and Case.